# Bool value is not triggering loader Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

**CONTEXT:**

I have a component called GenericTable which receives an Enumerable of T (classes) and displays it in a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwGza.png). Every column comes with 2 buttons one for update and inactivate which are eventcallbacks.

This is the razor code (I'll try to paste the part where the problem is produced I don't want to flood this question with code)

```
<tbody>
    @if (EnumList is not null)
    {

        @foreach (var item in EnumList)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
                {
                    string propVal = "";


                    if (Props.Contains(prop.Name))
                    {
                        <td>@prop.GetValue(item)</td>
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                        if (prop.Name == PropValue && PropValue is not null)
                        {
                            propVal = prop.GetValue(item)!.ToString()!;
                            bool itemLoader = false;
                            <td>       
                                <TelerikButton Icon="@FontIcon.Pencil" OnClick="() => GetPropValue(propVal, itemLoader)" Enabled="@(!itemLoader)">
                                    @(itemLoader ? "Actualizando": "Actualizar")
                                    <TelerikLoader Visible="@itemLoader"/>
                                    </TelerikButton>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <TelerikButton Icon="@FontIcon.Cancel">Inactivar</TelerikButton>
                            </td>
                        }
                }
            </tr>

        }
    }

    else
    {
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    }
</tbody>
```

As you can see in second If statement I'm using a local scope variable called itemLoader which is a bool variable that is used to trigger the Loader effect all of this is done with the GetPropValue method which takes the value of prop value (property) I'm passing and the value of itemLoader which in this case is false. You can see here the code behind of this component to see how this method behaves.

```
public partial class GenericTable<T> where T : class
{
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<T> EnumList { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<string> Props { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ButtonClicked { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? PropValue { get; set; }

    async Task GetPropValue(string propValue, bool itemLoader) {
       itemLoader = true;
       await ButtonClicked.InvokeAsync(propValue);
       itemLoader = false;
    }

}
```

Pretty simple when I click on the button the itemLoader is set to true and then to false.

**WHY IM DOING IT THIS WAY:**

Well before itemLoader I used to have a global variable called Loader in my code behind so everytime I click a button the GetPropValue method will set it to true, the thing doing it with a global varibale is that every button will trigger the loader effect as you can see even though is not the final result I wanted to achieved the global variable will work.

[image: Loader]

**THE PROBLEM:**

So now with the new approach I'm using with itemLoader for some reason it doesn't want to render the Loader effect and it's seems weird to me becuase I've tried to debug to see how the variable is behaving and the GetPropValue method sets the itemLoader to true in second If scope

[image: Debug1]
[image: Debug2]

But it doesn't render the the effect.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

I did add StateHasChanged() to the GetPropValue method but that didn't work.

**NOTE:**

I don't know if this useful but this is where I'm using my component

[image: Component]

and this the UpdateDept method

```
async Task UpdateDept(string deptId)
{
    try
    {
        ca_dept = await _ca_dept_Repository.Get(x => x.zdept_id == deptId);
        await _synchronization.updateDepartment(ca_dept!);
        displayAlert = true;
        displayMessage = $"El departamento {ca_dept!.name} fue actualizado.";
        displayAlertType = Alert.AlertStrings.Success;
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        displayAlert = false;
        displayMessage = default!;
        displayAlertType = default!;
        StateHasChanged();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        displayAlert = true;
        displayMessage = $"El departamento {ca_dept!.name} no pudo ser actualizado, hubo un error: {ex.Message}.";
        displayAlertType = Alert.AlertStrings.Error;
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(2500);
        displayAlert = false;
        displayMessage = default!;
        displayAlertType = default!;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your blazor rendermode?

Comment: @ShervinIvari Server side

Comment: If it is only server-side that's why it's not working, but if it is InteractiveServer the issue is something else